# Is there a built in method to take a value object or data transfer object and turn it into json with php?

Tags: php, json

I want to take a value object like

```
class Vo {

    private $blah;
    private $de;

    public function setBlah($blah) {
        $this->blah = $blah;
    }


    public function getBlah() {
        return $this->blah;
    }

    public function setDe($de) {
        $this->de = $de;
    }


    public function getDe() {
        return $this->de;
    }

}
```

And with out building it call a method that will either turn it into an array or even better build the JSON to look like `[{"blah" : "something set", "de" : "something set"}]`.  I'm just returning to PHP from Java/Jboss where I'm able to call a method on the object and it turns it into json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `json_encode()` because it doesn't work on private variables.  You'll need to define another function on the object:

```
function getJSON() {
    return  '[{"blah" : "'.$this->blah.'", "de" : "'.$this->de.'"}]';
}
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/vcwgsNDk)

*Edit:* Since PHP 5.4 PHP offers this easily:

```
class Vo implements JsonSerializable  {
    ...

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    ...
}

...

var_dump(json_encode($object));
```

Gives you:

```
string(29) "{"blah":"hammer","de":"time"}"
```

See [`The JsonSerializable interface`](http://php.net/class.jsonserializable). Even if you're below PHP 5.4 implement that function and then just call it manually:

```
json_encode($object->jsonSerialize());
```

So you have a common pattern of how to deal with it.

[Demo PHP 5.4](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X44hmn); [Demo PHP 5.2](http://codepad.org/IEnJQj8e)

Comment: This is what I was avoiding having to do but pretty sure your right in that this is the only option.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That will help me from keeping a test.php always open in my editor.

Comment: Even better suggest http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php and even if below PHP 5.4 name the function the same. Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qgQ5qv

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.  My question to me is why am I on 5.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `json_encode($object)`, and `json_decode($jsonObject)`.
Now, the only problem is, I'm not sure if the json_decode will return the proper object, or just a `StdClass` with the given properties.

I just tried doing a `json_decode()` on a simple json object, and it turns it into an object of the `stdClass` object, so you'll not be getting your `Vo` object back from json.
And as `dfsq` pointed out, json does not work on private properties.

If you do `serialize($object)`, `unserialize($string)`, then you can get the type back, but this is PHP specific, and not as portable as json.

Also take a look at this (php 5.4+):
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: The problem is that json_encode will return empty object representation like `{}`, because all the properties are private.

Comment: I thought json_encode() would only take an array. I'm going to test that real quick and with success hit the check.

Comment: when testing it with this I wasn't able to produce the desired results.    `code`  <?php

class Vo {

    private $blah;
    private $de;

    public function setBlah($blah) {
        $this->blah = $blah;
    }


    public function getBlah() {
        return $this->blah;
    }

    public function setDe($de) {
        $this->de = $de;
    }


    public function getDe() {
        return $this->de;
    }

}

$arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
 $vo = new VO();
 $vo->setBlah($i);
 $vo->setDe($i + $i);
 array_push($arr, $vo);
}

echo json_encode($arr);  `code`

Comment: Not sure how to format that code with the comment.  I thought `code` would do the trick

Comment: This is what that prints out  [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: @JustinCase See my answer for what you need.  I've also linked to http://codepad.org  which is a nice place to play with code and show the output.

Comment: @JustinCase SomeKittens is right, if you need private properties json_encoded, you'll need a custom method.
If you're using PHP 5.4 you can implement the JsonSerializable interface which will then work with json_encode() however you set it up

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your own code from scratch, answer suggested by @SomeKittens with @hakre edits is way to go, but sometimes you don't want / can't modify class code. You can easily `json_encode` any object with all properties, but you need to cast it to an array and clean up keys for private/protected property names:

```
/**
 * Encode object to JSON with protected/private variables with nested objects support.
 * @param mixed $object object to be jsonized
 * @param int $jsonEncodeOptions see JSON_* constants
 * @param bool $returnArray for recursive calls
 * @return string|array JSON string, associative array for recursive calls
 */
function json_encode_object($object, $jsonEncodeOptions = 0, $returnArray = FALSE){
    $ret = array();

    foreach((array)$object as $key => $value){

        if(is_resource($value)){
            //$rVal = NULL;
            continue;
        }elseif(is_object($value)){
            $rVal = json_encode_object($value, $jsonEncodeOptions, TRUE);
        }else{
            $rVal = $value;
        }

        $rKey = str_replace(
            array(
                chr(0)."*".chr(0), //protected
                chr(0).get_class($object).chr(0) //private
            )
            ,'',
            $key        
        );

        $ret[$rKey] = $rVal;
    }

    return $returnArray?$ret:json_encode($ret, $jsonEncodeOptions);
}
```